# Install Firefox ESR on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: firefox, 18.04

I would like to replace the version of Firefox that is already installed with Firefox ESR on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have downloaded it from http://www.mozilla.org/firefox/organizations/all.html#en-US

But I couldn't configure it successfully as I could in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo tar -xvjf firefox-x.x.tar.bz2 -C /opt
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

So I have reinstalled Ubuntu completely.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: These commands install Firefox ESR 52 in US language: 

- sudo apt-get remove firefox
 - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa 
- sudo apt-get update 
- sudo apt-get install firefox-esr

But it worked.